# Register trackingevent for all background jobs?

Tags: multithreading, powershell, event-handling, powershell-5.1

Good afternoon,

I've been working with trying to register an event based on when *all* jobs are completed. Im able to successfully register one, but id like to get a message  pop-up once all background jobs are completed. Anyone familiar with how to do so?

I attempted the following, but it errors out saying jobs is null:

```
1..10 | ForEach-Object -Process {
    Start-Job { Start-Sleep $_ } -Name "$_" | Out-Null} -OutVariable $jobs

Register-ObjectEvent $jobs StateChanged -Action {
    [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('Done')
        $eventSubscriber | Unregister-Event
        $eventSubscriber.Action | Remove-Job
    } | Out-Null
```

I feel like a `Do{}Until()` loop can do it but, im not sure how to register that to check until the job has completed. Also tried to follow along with some ways other people have done it using different languages, but, I cant pick it up.

I don't want to post everything ive tried so this post doesn't bore anyone. Searched on google as well but, I couldn't find much on registering an object for multiple jobs.

**EDIT**
Heres what does work:

```
$job = Start-Job -Name GetLogFiles { Start-Sleep 10 }

Register-ObjectEvent $job StateChanged -Action {
    [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('Done')
        $eventSubscriber | Unregister-Event
        $eventSubscriber.Action | Remove-Job
} | Out-Null
```

Which is what id like to happened, but to evaluate all jobs, not just one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what a personally use when monitoring running jobs:

```
$jobs= 1..10 | ForEach-Object -Process {
    Start-Job { Start-Sleep $using:_ ; "job {0} done" -f $using:_ } -Name "$_"
}

do{
    $i = (Get-Job -State Completed).count
    $progress = @{
        Activity = 'Jobs completed'
        Status = "$i of {0}" -f $jobs.Count
        PercentComplete = $i / $jobs.count *  100
    }
    Write-Progress @progress
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 10
}
until($i -eq $jobs.Count)

$result = Get-Job | Receive-Job

$jobs | Remove-Job
```

Of course, under certain scenarios where I know some jobs might fail I change the `until(...)` condition for something different and the `do {...}` contains the logic for restarting failing jobs.

#### Edit 1:

It's worth mentioning that `Start-Job` is not worth your time if you're interested in multithreading, it has been proven to be slower than a linear loop in many scenarios. You should be looking at the [`ThreadJob Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/threadjob/?view=powershell-7.1)

#### Edit 2:

After some testing, this worked for me:

```
# Clear the Event queue
Get-EventSubscriber|Unregister-Event

# Clear the Job queue
Get-Job|Remove-Job

1..10 | ForEach-Object -Process {
    $job = Start-Job { Sleep -Seconds (1..20|Get-Random) } -Name "$_"
    
    Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $job -EventName StateChanged -Action {
        $eventSubscriber | Unregister-Event
        $eventSubscriber.Action | Remove-Job
        if(-not (Get-EventSubscriber))
        {
            [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show('Done')
        }
    } | Out-Null
}
```

At first I didn't even know this was possible so thanks for pointing this out. Great question :)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion! Was trying to figure out how to register that `Do{}Until()` in an event. I simplified it to `Do{$jobs=Get-Jobs -State Running}Until($jobs.State -ne running)`, which should do it for me but, id like to be able to use the console while it runs in the background and have that event notify me once its done. Got any clue on how that can be done?

Comment: To your update on your post,I work in a govt environment and installing modules isn't really allowed. I was able to register a single event based on a job, and once it completed, it gave me the pop-up i was looking for while i was doing something else. Just not sure how to go about it for all of them. If that makes sense?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala you mean if you start a job that takes say 1 minute to run you're able to  use the console after the job starts and still get a popup notification when it finishes? I tried your code and is not working for me: `Register-ObjectEvent : Cannot register for the specified event. An event with the name 'StateChanged' does not exist.`

Comment: right, what i posted wont work. It's what i want to work. Look at my edit to what does work for a single job. It allows me to interact with the console and itll give me a pop-up once its complete.

Comment: I cant help but feel like it is possible. I just don't have the smarts to figure it out. Documentation really doesn't help me here either.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala Check out my edit, great question man. I learnt something new today :)

Comment: Oh man, your last edit did it. I could cry rn! Man, I was stumped for like 7 hours trying to get that to work. HOW!?!?!?!?! Can you barney style it for me so I can understand whats going on?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala What does "barney style" mean lol? sure, I can explain how it works I believe there is an option to chat in SO, if there is one you can open a chat window :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231348/discussion-between-abraham-zinala-and-santiago-squarzon).